# Changing CSS with html onClick window.print()?

Tags: html, css

I have a web page that has `CSS` settings to put a 15% margin around the page so it looks better for the user. I have a button that allows them to print the page, but the same margin is applied. The button has a setting to be hidden when printing, and I'm wondering if there is a way to remove the margins or change the margins for printing when they click the button. The code I have for the button right now is:

```css
body {
 margin-left: 20%;
 margin-right: 20%;
}
```

```html
<button
  id="printButton"
  name="printButton"
  class="btn btn-primary hidden-print"
  onClick="window.print()"
  type="button">
  Print for My Records
</button>
```

I'd like that change the margins to something like 1% or 2% when the `window.print()` page comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make it difficult! Just use the media query `@media print` in your stylesheet.

```css
body {
 margin-left: 20%;
 margin-right: 20%;
}

@media print and (min-width: 480px) {
  body {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  
  #printButton {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<button
  id="printButton"
  name="printButton"
  class="btn btn-primary hidden-print"
  onClick="window.print()"
  type="button">
  Print for My Records
</button>
```

Comment: This worked to correct the margin issue, but now the buttons marked as "hidden-print" show up on the print page. Is there a way to implement this media thing and still have it so the buttons don't show up on the page to print?

Comment: I edited the above code by adding a rule called `#printButton`. Check it again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to alter the margins defined upon button click for the print layout. Just use the `@page` at-rule to modify the margin properties when the page is being printed.

```
@page {
  margin: 1cm;
}

body {
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
}
```

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page)

As this might have compatibility issues with Safari, you can also use the `print` media-query:

```
body {
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
}

@media print {
  body {
    margin: 1%;
  }
}
```